# save picture and open in imageview

Tags: android, image, view

When I take a picture, the picture will saved on the hard drive and open the picture in imageview.

In my command the picture will be saved but the app is crashing.

```
public class Note  extends Activity {

TextView t;
ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.note);
   iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.photo);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });


}
public void button (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Note2.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==0)
    {
    Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);

    }}
}
```

How do I rewrite the command to make it work?

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==0)
        {
        Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that your `Manifest` has this permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Second, your `onActivityResult` method should be like this with declaring a `File` and store the `Bitmap` into the device as following:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
switch(requestCode){
  case 0:
    final File file = getTempFile(this);
    try {
      Bitmap captureBmp = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file) );
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  break;
  }
}
}
```

Here is a very good [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20200222151624/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2010/10/take-picture-in-android-with.html) on capturing images